# Difference between affine quotient variety and a global quotient orbifold

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cv.complex-variables, orbifolds

Given a smooth affine variety $X$ and a finite group $G$ acting by automorphisms on $X$, the quotient space $X/G$ has the structure of an affine variety which is in general not smooth. However, in the literature some authors talk about an orbifold $X/G$.

I would like to understand what the difference between a global quotient affine variety $X/G$ and a global quotient orbifold is. What more structure does the orbifold have than an affine variety or vice versa? Are the structure sheaves on both spaces different or are they the same?  Can someone with knowledge on the subject elaborate on that?

Comment: "both notions seem to coincide in the algebraic case", no, that's wrong, they coincide only if $G$ acts freely. In fact, the quotient orbifold is (very roughly) the quotient of $X$ by $G$ as if $G$ acted freely on $X$.

Comment: @abx Is the quotient "orbifold" basically the quotient algebraic space (when the base field is real or complex)?

Comment: @Z. M: No, it's the "stacky" quotient. It is not an algebraic space if the action s not free.

Comment: @abx Thanks, so it is a DM stack, and the "algebraic" quotient is its coarse moduli space? And is "algebraic" one also called GIT quotient?

Comment: @Z. M: Yes, exactly. Note that for a finite group the GIT quotient is just the ordinary quotient.

Comment: @abx, In nLab, https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/orbifold, they write that the orbifold is a special (non-smooth) algebraic variety with “orbifold singularities” whatever the latter means. Now, for a smooth affine variety $X$ with a finite group  $G$ on it, how many different ways are there to view it as a singular variety- once as an affine variety and once as an orbifold? Is an orbifold a singular variety? Or is the statement in nLab wrong then?

Comment: I also edited the question and removed the statement which according to abx is wrong.

Comment: At the link you provide, I read: 'Definition: An orbifold is a stack presented by an orbifold groupoid'.

Comment: …And the sentence just before this definition  says: “ A singular variety is called an (algebraic) orbifold if it has only so-called orbifold singularities.” So, the orbifold according to the source I am citing is a singular variety. Is this false?

Comment: @abx, One more thing. If the action of $G$ on $X$ is free, then are you saying that $X/G$ is an algebraic space, which is a special case of an orbifold? Is that the statement? Are algebraic spaces different from orbifolds or are they a special case of orbifolds?

Comment: If the action is free, $X/G$ is a smooth affine variety. I don't understand why you want to put algebraic spaces in the picture.

Comment: Which is contained in which? A variety is an orbifold or an orbifold is a singular variety or both structures are completely different and exist parallely to one another ? In the analytic case, an orbifold is by definition a complex space, which makes it easier to understand.  In the algebraic setting, there is this obscure mess with algebraic spaces, moduli spaces and then quotient stacks whose relation to ordinary varieties I find insufficiently well explained. Can you write a brief answer explaining the relation between a quotient variety and DM stack?